# How to load more than 10 files with range in executable args?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I have this working command line expression:

`program --files path_to_mydir/mydata_[0-9].csv`

I would like to go from `[0-100]` but this is not working.

`program --files path_to_mydir/mydata_[0-100].csv`

Also, bonus ask, what do you call `[0-10]` wrt shell scripting and bash scripts?

Thanks

Edit: while similar this question is not asking about `ls`

Comment: Regarding your "edit": The command used is irrelevant. It's the shell expanding the pattern on the command line _before_ invoking the command. The fact that you use  some generic `program` and the duplicate uses  `ls` does not make the questions different in essence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[...]` is a bracket expression.  It matches a single character, always, so you can't use `[0-100]` as that would just match a single `0` or `1` (in the POSIX locale)

In the `zsh` shell, you could use `<0-100>` for a numerical range globbing pattern, but that won't work in `bash`:

```bsh
program --files path_to_mydir/mydata_<0-100>.csv
```

In `bash`, you *could* use a brace expansion instead:

```bsh
program --files path_to_mydir/mydata_{0..100}.csv
```

but you have to be aware of the difference between this and a filename globbing pattern.  A brace expansion, as the one just above, *generates strings*, regardless of what filenames are available, while a filename globbing pattern *matches existing names*.  This means that a brace expansion could potentially feed your program filenames that does not exist.

You *could* use `[...]` to match the files with numbers between 0 and 100, but you would have to make it three patterns, one for each length of numbers:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

program --files \
    path_to_mydir/mydata_[0-9].csv \
    path_to_mydir/mydata_[1-9][0-9].csv \
    path_to_mydir/mydata_[1][0][0].csv
```

The first would match names containing the digits `0` through to `9`,  the second would match the names containing `10` through to `99`, and the last would match the name containing `100`.

Would you want to match zero-filled integers:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

program --files \
    path_to_mydir/mydata_[0][0-9][0-9].csv \
    path_to_mydir/mydata_[1][0][0].csv
```

I set the `nullglob` shell option in both variations of this code to make sure that any pattern that is not matching any names is removed, and not left unexpanded.

---

User fra-san noticed that you could use a combination of the brace expansion above with something that would force the shell to trigger a  globbing pattern match:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
program --files path_to_mydir/[m]ydata_{0..100}.csv
```

The inclusion of `[m]` in the string (a pattern matching the character `m`) would force the shell to treat each of the strings that the brace expansion creates as a separate globbing pattern.  Since we're using `nullglob`, the patterns that do not correspond to existing names would be removed from the argument list.

Note that this would generate and expand 101 globbing patterns, whereas the other approaches using globbing in this answer uses two or three patterns.

Comment: Note that the bash one won't match on `mydata_001.csv` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, it would not, as the user mentioned `0-100`, not `000-100`. I'll make a note about that. Thanks.

Comment: Having fun with `nullglob` and brace expansion, `[m]ydata_{0..100}.csv`.

Comment: @fra-san Yeah, that would work... thanks.

Comment: Or `mydata_*(0){0..100}.csv` to be functionally equivalent to zsh's `mydata_<0-100>.csv(n)`

Answer (score 3):

The `[...]` glob operator, like the similar regexp operator matches a character (or possibly collating element) in the specified set.

It only matches one character. Inside `[...]`, you can have

- individual characters, like `[abc]` which matches on either `a` or `b` or `c`
- character classes, like `[[:digit:]]` which matches on characters for which `isdigit()` returns true.
- ranges like `[a-f]` for characters (or collating elements) that sort in between `a` and `f` (beware it may and often does include more than just `abcdef` as things like `é` for instance fall in that range).
- more esoteric ones like `[[=e=]]` equivalent classes, `[[.x.]]` a collating element given by name...

And you can combine all those. For instance `[[:blank:][:digit:]a-f123]` whould match on a character that is either a blank, digit, or sorts between a and f or is 1, 2 or 3.

Your `[0-100]` matches on a character that sorts between 0 and 1 or 0 or 0, so either one of `01٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦౸೦൦෦๐໐༠༳၀႐០៰᠐᥆᧐᪀᪐᭐᮰᱀᱐⁰₀↉⓪⓿〇㍘꘠꣐꤀꧐꧰꩐꯰０` (or possibly more or less depending on the system, locale and version of `bash`).

To match on on a sequence of one or more characters that make up integer numbers 0 to 100 in decimal, you'd need to use `extglob`, and break it down as:

```
*(0)@(100|[123456789]?([0123456789]))
```

That is, any number of 0s followed by either 100 or a 1..9 digit optionally followed by a 0..9 digit.

Or you could switch to `zsh` which has a dedicated glob operator to match on strings that make up decimal integers: `<0-100>` here. In `zsh`, you can also use the `n` glob qualifier to make sure the files are ordered numerically so that `10` comes after `2` for instance:

```
program --files path_to_mydir/mydata_<0-100>.csv(n)
```